# MySQL GROUP BY Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to perform a GROUP BY on 2 columns separately...

In common terms, I'd like the query to say: GROUP BY column 1, then once this grouping has been performed, and the rows returned have been refined, go back to the top and GROUP BY column 2 to refine the rows returned again.

For instance, instead of stating:
GROUP BY column_1, column_2

I want to state (I Understand this is incorrect syntax):
GROUP BY column_1
GROUP BY column_2

If this is unclear I can include a sample query with expected returned results.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
select ...
from (
    select ...
    from some_table
    where ...
    group by column1
) as dt
group by column2
```

That's the closest thing I can think of that matches what your question appears to be asking.

Comment: I've discovered a way to enhance my question which should make it easier to understand and useful for readers with similar issues.  I will re-post it with the necessary changes made.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you can group by multiple columns in mysql. The query is:
`select * from table group by col1, col2`

But you can't get answer as you want as. So you've another chance to get correct answer in mysql. That is, you've to use subqueries.
`select * from (select * from table group by col2) tabl group by col1`